# PostGIS Shapefile Import Manager error

Tags: postgis

I am trying to import .shp to PgAdmin III but is error because of "dbf file can not be opened" and I dont understand why.
[image]

Comment: First thing that I would test is to rename shapefile into something simple like test.shp and place is into c:\data for avoiding problems caused by special characters and spaces. All parts of the shapefile must naturally be renamed and moved.

Comment: try a folder without the dot and diacritic characters (example c:\temp)

Comment: It is works , but second problem is: Importing with configuration: kraj, public, geom, C:\data\kraj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Unable to convert field name to UTF-8 (iconv reports "Illegal byte sequence"). Current encoding is "UTF-8". Try "LATIN1" (Western European), or one of the values described at http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/.
Shapefile import failed.

Comment: and when I try LATIN1: Importing with configuration: kraj, public, geom, C:\data\kraj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]

Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xa1 0x74

Shapefile import failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error  happens:

- If the dbf is missing or corrupt (note it should have the same name as the .shp (but with .dbf extension).
- If the file is present and not obviously corrupt (Like it has more than 0 bytes)

Try opening the .dbf file in LibreOffice spreadsheet or Microsoft Excel to verify it's readable.

Also as noted by some others, probably would help to have a folder name with just ASCII characters.

Comment: It is works , but second problem is: Importing with configuration: kraj, public, geom, C:\data\kraj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0 Unable to convert field name to UTF-8 (iconv reports "Illegal byte sequence"). Current encoding is "UTF-8". Try "LATIN1" (Western European), or one of the values described at gnu.org/software/libiconv. Shapefile import failed

Comment: and when I try LATIN1: Importing with configuration: kraj, public, geom, C:\data\kraj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0 Shapefile type: Polygon PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2] Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xa1 0x74 Shapefile import failed.

Comment: Have you tried one of the other encodings described on that page: gnu.org/software/libiconv. Sometimes there is a cpg file included that might give some clue.  Newer shp2pgsql automatically reads the file as I recall.  We may not have that logic in shp2pgsql-gui.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was putting the files in my C or D disk. I guess it just for avoiding directories with strange caracteres as names or blank spaces.